# Facebook Graph API. How to delete Video?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I followed this page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video

The video deleting is required access token with publish_actions.
But the publish_actions permission has been deprecated.
When I try to delete a video it return me an error:

> "(#200) The permission(s) publish_actions are not available. It has
>   been deprecated. If you want to provide a way for your app users to
>   share content to Facebook, we encourage you to use our Sharing
>   products instead."

Is it possible to delete video using facebook graph api?

PS: also, could not find how to delete video in facebook's asset library. It looks like it is not possible to delete any video.

Comment: was that video uploaded with your app? afaik you can only delete stuff that happened with the app anyway.

Comment: For both types, from my app and from facebook directly. There is no option to delete them. @luschn

Comment: Are you talking about a user video or a page video?

Comment: I'm talking about adaccount videos from endpoint /v.xx/ad_account_id/advideos

Comment: i have the same problem

Comment: I also have this issue. It's weird that there's not delete button.